# Does my book lie about $\int \frac{\arccos(\frac{x}{2})}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I dropped out of university for 3 years or so and now I am want to come back so I started solving some calculus assignments in order to wash off my rusty knowledge of it. Anyway, as you can probably guess I started with the most simple indefinite integrals in order to recall and practice the main integral table formulas, where I met this one 
$\int \frac{\arccos(\frac{x}{2})}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$ as you can see it looks pretty simple when the place where I've taken this integral tries to convince me that $\sqrt{4-x^2} = \sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{2})^2}$ sadly I cannot see it (maybe because of my long gone mathematics skills and intuition).

Can you please guys try to elaborate on this? I tried wolfram but one of it steps is 
[image: wolfram step]

and I fail to understand how $du= - \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$

Comment: You are missing a factor. I am sure you can show that $\sqrt{4-x^2}=2 \sqrt{1-(\tfrac{x}2)^2}$ holds... We moreover have (because of the chain rule) $\frac{d}{dx} \arccos(x/2) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}2)^2}}\cdot \frac12$

Comment: Aha, so that's whats missing in my book, yes this seems obvious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not true that $\sqrt{4-x^2}=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x2\right)^2}$. What you have is$$\sqrt{4-x^2}=\sqrt{4-4\left(\frac x2\right)^2}=2\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x2\right)^2}.$$On the other hand, since $\arccos'(x)=-\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, then, if $u=\arccos\left(\frac x2\right)$, then$$\mathrm du=-\frac12\cdot\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x2\right)^2}}=-\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}.$$

Comment: Dont we have one minus in front of $\frac{1}{2}$ of $du$?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer. Thank you.